# How to indicate an effective date on historical table using audit capabilities of Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I have a `Product` table with a name column and would like to maintain a history of name changes in the `ProductHistory` table. (The `Product` table also has a few other columns. I don't need to track data changes for those cols.)

[image]

My application will use the `ProductHistory` table when a user requests to run a report for a given date. The report needs to show the product name(s) as of the report date.

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2 and including Spring Boot's Starter Data JPA dependency. I plan to use [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) within [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/envers/docs/1.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/) to help accomplish my goal. I have read through [this doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.auditing) but not sure how to specify an effective date on the `ProductHistory`.

I've enabled JPA auditing:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class DatabaseConfig {
    //config items
}
```

Using [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.auditing) as a reference, I should have the entity as:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date effectiveDateUtc;

    private String name;

    //other fields corresponding to othercols
 }
```

But `effectiveDateUtc` is not a field / column of `Product`. How do I indicate that `effectiveDateUtc` is a property of `ProductHistory`?

**Update**

I've been unable to find a way to accomplish the above using audit capbilties of Spring Data JPA. Using the answer posted by Naros  / Hibernate envers though, I was able to accomplish my goals.

Besides what Naros posted, here's what else I found that I needed to do to get this to work with my Spring application:

Add the required jars to my gradle build:

```
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.2.10.Final')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final')
compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.1')
```

Created the requisite schema in the DB.

I also set up an integration test case to verify that I could do reporting type queries on the revision data. To do this, I needed to get the entity manager and pass that to the audit reader factory:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=ProductDataApplication.class)
public class ProductRepositoryTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testEnversQuerying() {
        AuditReader ar = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        Product revisions = ar.find(Product.class, 1L, new Date());
        // assert code
    }
}
```

As Naros surmised, I need to also store the user id associated with a revision. I did that as follows:

```
public class UserRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        UserRevision revision = (UserRevision) revisionEntity;

        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null ||
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() == null) {
            revision.setModifiedBy("system");
        } else {
            revision.setModifiedBy(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize you're probably looking for a Spring-related response; however, I can at least provide you the details of how this would work if you were using Hibernate Envers directly.

1. Lets get the entity setup:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Product {
     @Id
     private Integer id;
     @Audited
     private String name;
     // other attributes
   }
   ```

   As you can see, we're basically saying that we simply want to audit the product's name.  Any other attributes that you have mapped in the entity will simply be ignored because the class isn't annotated with `@Audited` and we specifically targetted the property `name` only.
2. Contrary to the `ProductHistory` model you illustrated, Envers will actually create two tables for you.  The first will be a `Product_AUD` table which will be where we store the audit log about changes that is made to your `Product` entity.

   The `Product_AUD` table will contain columns that closely resemble this:

   ```
   REV INT NOT NULL         <- Foreign Key to the Revision Entity Table (REVINFO)
   PRODUCT_ID INT NOT NULL  <- Your PK from your Product Table
   NAME VARCHAR(255)        <- The name column annotated with @Audited
   REVTYPE INT              <- Revision type (0=INSERT,1=UPDATE,2=DELETE)
   ```

   The next table that will be constructed will be `REVINFO`.  By default this table is constructed with only two columns and will look something like the following:

   ```
   REV INT NOT NULL         <- The revision number (PK)
   REVTSTMP BIGINT          <- The time in milliseconds
   ```

   The reason that Envers constructs the models in this fashion is because its not uncommon to have multiple entities be modified in a since transaction and rather than duplicate a lot of the revision-specific attributes across all entity audit tables, we consolidated it in a normalized fashion and store that data in the `REVINFO` table.

The one thing that you might want that it seems you tend to get directly with Spring Data is to be able to capture the user and perhaps other attributes that pertain to the environment at the time the revision occurred.  You're in luck because Envers provides a quick and painless way to do that too.

1. Define a custom revision entity.  This can be done by simply extending one of the default implementations we provide for you or you can simply create a fully functional entity.  My personal preference and suggestion is to create your own full implementation.  This entity basically extends the default `REVINFO` table with custom columns.  Here's an example that mirrors the default table setup with one additional column:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "REVINFO")
   @RevisionEntity(MyRevisionEntityListener.class)
   public class MyRevisionEntity {
     @Id
     @RevisionNumber
     @Column(name = "REV", nullable = false, updatable = false)
     private Integer id;
     @RevisionTimestamp
     @Column(name = "REVTSTMP", nullable = false, updatable = false)
     private Long timestamp;
     @Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY", length = 100)
     private String modifiedBy;
     // getter/setters and perhaps other attributes
   }
   ```
2. Define the revision entity listener that is used to populate your custom attributes on your revision entity instance:

   ```
   class MyRevisionEntityListener implements RevisionListener {
     @Override
     public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
     }
   }
   ```

   In this listener, what you'll want to do is to fetch whatever context information you want to inject into the Envers revision entity and set it on your revision entity class.

   One way to get information into this listener is to store it in a ThreadLocal variable and access that variable in the listener callback.  If you're using Spring Security as an example, it already done this for you in their `SecurityContextHolder` thread local container.  If you're using other means, you can simply take their implementation as an example.

As I mentioned initially, this really doesn't address your Spring Data needs directly, but it does illustrate how that happens with Envers should you decide to use it directly.

Comment: Envers is awesome! And it works well with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA such as repositories, etc. Thanks for your post! I did more research by reading the [user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers). Then, set up a few integration tests to help learn and prove out that it could meet the application's needs. It can do that and a lot more! Looking forward to using it in my app code.